# Android not importing/syncing external libraries

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I recently changed my windows OS and freshly installed Android Studio. I cloned my Android project from Git which is working perfectly. But now in latest thing its not working. I don't know what's missing. [import classes showing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydori.png)

I didn't changed gradle files.
My project level gradle file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
           url 'https://maven.google.com/'
           name 'Google'
       }
      //maven { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com"}
      google()
   }
   dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
      classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
      // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
      // in the individual module build.gradle files
   }
  }
  allprojects {
   repositories {
      jcenter()
      // maven { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com"}
      mavenCentral()
      google()
      maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
   }
 }
 task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

My app level gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
         classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
    }
}
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

 repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    google()
    jcenter()
 }

 android {
     compileSdkVersion 27
     buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
     useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
     defaultConfig {
         applicationId "com.cir****.d********"
         vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
         minSdkVersion 16
         targetSdkVersion 27
         versionCode 40
         versionName "6.1.0"
         multiDexEnabled true
     }

  buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
         }
   }

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader'
    exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter'
    exclude 'META-INF/jersey-module-version'
    exclude 'META-INF/services/com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.InjectableProvider'
}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    abortOnError false
}
aaptOptions
        {
            cruncherEnabled = false
        }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
    implementation files('libs/json-simple-1.1.jar')
    implementation files('libs/httpmime-4.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('libs/PGSDK_V2.1')
    implementation files('libs/apache-mime4j-0.6.jar')
    implementation files('libs/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar')
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.4@aar'
    implementation 'com.edwardvanraak:MaterialBarcodeScanner:0.0.6-ALPHA'
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.razorpay:checkout:1.4.7'
    implementation 'com.msg91.sendotp.library:library:2.8'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
       transitive = true
    }
   implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
   implementation 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.4.3'
   implementation 'gun0912.ted:tedbottompicker:1.1.0'
   implementation 'com.kofigyan.stateprogressbar:stateprogressbar:0.0.6'
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have done Clean, Rebuilt, invalidate caches/Restart,sync project with gradle files, deleted .gradle folder and wasted 1 day trying to solve this. I am ready to share further code if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of scratching my head, I solved this headache in another way. It gives the above error if I clone the master branch through SSH key. So for a trail I merged all the developing branches and cloned. The headache is still there. 
So I opened Git Bash and clone a specific branch (not master) which is mine with following command.
 
`git clone --single-branch -b sub_branch_name url` 
The problem solved for now. I don't know what problem is with master branch.